# How to customize Developer Exception Page in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

It's common in the `Configure` method of the Startup.cs file to have code that looks like this:

```
if(env.IsDevelopment()) {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions() { SourceCodeLineCount = 10 });
}
```

The `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` line causes detailed information to be displayed in the browser when an exception occurs which is quite helpful for debugging.

I'm sure you've seen the output, it looks something like this:

[image]

This is a great start, but sometimes as developers we add additional information to exceptions to provide details about the error.  The `System.Exception` class has a `Data` collection that can be used for storing such information.  So for example my custom `AppException` that inherits from `Exception` has a constructor that accepts a private message in addition to the standard exception message, like so:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Application Exception. 
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="message">Message that can be displayed to a visitor.</param>
 /// <param name="privateMessage">Message for developers to pinpoint the circumstances that caused exception.</param>
 /// <param name="innerException"></param>
    public AppException(string message, string privateMessage, Exception innerException = null) 
        : base(message, innerException) {
        
        //Placing it in the exception Data collection makes the info available in the debugger
        this.Data["PrivateMessage"] = privateMessage;
    }
```

So as you can imaging, it'd be nice if the developer exception page displayed the `PrivateMessage` from the `Exception` (if it's an `AppException`) along with all the other information.  I've looked high and low to figure out how to customize or augment the information displayed on the developer exception page but haven't been able to find any good information on it.

**How can I customize or augment the information displayed on the developer exception page?**

Comment: My does not show the line numbers is this a customisation

Comment: Trying adding the page via this `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions() { SourceCodeLineCount = 10 });`  I see that's how I'm actually doing it.  I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: thanks mate didnt expect a quick response.

Comment: @rogue39nin - No worries, would appreciate an upvote to the question ;-)

Comment: its such an anooying page gives nothing to the dev like and looks ugly for the user is their a way to overide the page.

Comment: its still not showing the plus icons to see the source in edge or chrome any ideas.

Comment: Perhaps if you have debugging turned off and the debug symbols are not available.  I just testing it in case perhaps the page had changed since I posted this question but even in dotnet core 3.1 which I'm now running it looks the same for me (includes line numbers).  I couldn't reproduce though.  Probably best to post a question on stack overflow.   To display a more friendly page use app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); instead of  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); .  Reminder, comments are not supposet to be used as chat on stack overflow ;-) Hope I was helpful however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219437/discussion-between-rogue39nin-and-ron-c).

Answer (score 3):

The `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` extension method is shorthand for adding the `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` into the request/response pipeline. You can find the full source code for `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/082d505977d72c75b68935c93c21feded6928e5f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage), including the middleware itself and the views. It should make an excellent base for rolling your own custom middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  From your link I identified that it uses `ExceptionDetailsProvider` located at https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/ffb7c20fb22a31ac31d3a836a8455655867e8e16/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.StackTrace.Sources/ExceptionDetailsProvider.cs and the actual html output is done by `ErrorPage` found at https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/Obsolete/ErrorPage.cs   Unfortunately `ErrorPage` is the generated .cs not the .cshtml. Arg.

Comment: @RonC The second link you posted is in the `Obsolete` namespace - is this not the cshtml file you're looking for? https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/ErrorPage.cshtml

Comment: @MarkMacneilBikeio Updated.

Comment: @Polynomial  The above link does't has implementation details for ErrorDetails = _exceptionDetailsProvider.GetDetails(ex) 

Since its private method. So we can not customize it nor there is a interface to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` has the design problem - it assumes that all exceptions are 500 and it starts sending the response right away. It means, it's impossible to correct the behavior of this middleware by applying another custom middleware on top of that.

So, there are two options: replicate its nice HTML error page generation in your code or create your own dev exception page (I'd advise to dump current exception and the context in JSON and return it to the client).