# Can Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPage be extended?

Tags: exception, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In .NET Core you can easily add a [detailed exception page for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling):

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

This then gives you the exception details:

[image: DeveloperExceptionPage]

However, I'd like to include additional exception detail - for instance the SQL query attempted when the exception is a `SqlException`.

I can write my own exception handler from scratch with `app.UseExceptionHandler`, but I'd rather extend the built-in error. For instance by adding a tab to the results including additional info.

Is it possible to extend the information on this exception page?

Comment: Are you using EntityFrameworkCore? How about using the `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage()` middleware?  https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore/DatabaseErrorPageExtensions.cs#L21. You'll need to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore` package

Comment: @Tseng No, I'm not using EF and it's not just SQL exceptions I want to extend (they're just the easiest example). I'll have a dig into the source you've linked and see if there's something I can use.

Comment: The developer exceptions are located here https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage but at the first look at them it doesn't seem very extensible though. It's just a try/catch around the next() call and an Razor template to display it and none of the important calls in the middleware are virtual

Comment: I asked a very similar question just a few days ago and have received very little response so far.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882493/how-to-customize-developer-exception-page-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @RonC Yeah, that's very similar, though it looks like the answer is "roll your own middleware" - I know how to do that, but it feels like repeating work someone else has already done.

Comment: @Keith totally agree.